# Heroku start and the exit

Tags: java, heroku, web-deployment

What's wrong here? Suddenly Heroku wants to look for `favicon.ico`.

```
2021-12-08T08:25:54.262142+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-12-08T08:25:56.851230+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-12-08T08:25:59.201817+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-12-08T08:25:59.201829+00:00 app[web.1]: > be-tracker@1.0.0 start /app
2021-12-08T08:25:59.201829+00:00 app[web.1]: > node ./web/dataControl.js
2021-12-08T08:25:59.201829+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-12-08T08:25:59.613576+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2021-12-08T08:25:59.719749+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-12-08T08:26:13.640408+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=morning-waters-38576.herokuapp.com request_id=f58ed5f9-041d-4316-98c4-8cd3838c033c fwd="14.192.216.128" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-12-08T08:26:15.486269+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=morning-waters-38576.herokuapp.com request_id=97551151-a94b-415d-947d-643a5238b22d fwd="14.192.216.128" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

What should I do?

Comment: The `favicon.ico` has nothing to do with it. Browsers always request one, but not having one doesn't break your app. It's the _previous_ line, about the request to `/` failing that's important. Unfortunately there's no detail there at all. Please [edit] your question and show us `web/dataControl.js`. I suggest you also add some logging to that file so you can see what's actually happening.

Comment: its an empty file. I thought i only have to put a js file or should i include something in the file?

Comment: "its an empty file. I thought i only have to put a js file or should i include something in the file?"—your `web/dataControl.js` file is _empty?_ So... what do you expect your application to _do?_

Comment: actually im using jsp and dont use any javascript. Do you have suggestions on what can i do to make it run?

Comment: Then why are are you trying to run `node ./web/dataControl.js`? Shouldn't you be doing `java -jar ...` or something?